# Content After Slider Is Overwriting Slider. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, position

I am working on a slider that is working perfectly but the problem is that the content of web-page after the slider is overwriting on slider's 2-3 slides. I don't want to fix the height of slider but also want to show after slider content after every slides of slider. The code is shared below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",so_init,false):window.attachEvent("onload",so_init);
var d=document, imgs = new Array(), zInterval = null, current=0, pause=false;
function so_init() {
    if(!d.getElementById || !d.createElement)return;
    imgs = d.getElementById("gallery").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(i=1;i<imgs.length;i++) imgs[i].xOpacity = 0;
    imgs[0].style.display = "block";
    imgs[0].xOpacity = .99;
    setTimeout(so_xfade,1000);
}
function so_xfade() {
    cOpacity = imgs[current].xOpacity;
    nIndex = imgs[current+1]?current+1:0;
    nOpacity = imgs[nIndex].xOpacity;
    cOpacity-=.05; 
    nOpacity+=.05;
    imgs[nIndex].style.display = "block";
    imgs[current].xOpacity = cOpacity;
    imgs[nIndex].xOpacity = nOpacity;
    setOpacity(imgs[current]); 
    setOpacity(imgs[nIndex]);
    if(cOpacity<=0) {
        imgs[current].style.display = "none";
        current = nIndex;
        setTimeout(so_xfade,3000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(so_xfade,50);
    }
    function setOpacity(obj) {
        if(obj.xOpacity>.99) {
            obj.xOpacity = .99;
            return;
        }
        obj.style.opacity = obj.xOpacity;
        obj.style.MozOpacity = obj.xOpacity;
        obj.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (obj.xOpacity*100) + ")";
    }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#slider {max-height:700px;background:url(https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-LLFEz-EyGbk/UyV9SbGPuhI/AAAAAAAAMgY/JNqf8X11dbk/s220/slider-loader.gif) #2e2e2e no-repeat 50% 50%;}
#gallery {padding:0;position:relative;margin:0 auto;max-width:1920px;}
#gallery li {list-style-type:none;width:100%;display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
.gallery_img img {max-width:100%;}
.gallery_text {width:100%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;position:absolute;top:-20%;left:0%;}
.gallery_text h2 {padding:0;line-height:70px;font-size:50px;font-weight:inherit;color:#fff;}
.gallery_text p {margin:20px 0;line-height:24px;font-size:20px;color:#ffee66;}
.gallery_text a {background:#77aa00;display:inline-block;padding:20px 70px;font-size:18px;font-weight:700;text-transform:uppercase;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;}
.gallery_text a:hover {background:#fff;color:#000;}
</style>
This Is The DIV Or Text Before The Slider.
<div class='clear'/>
<div id='slider'>
<ul id='gallery'>
<li style='position:relative!important;'>
<div class='gallery_img'><img alt='Google' src='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Nh50j1-Bqws/UyV9Pv_wd3I/AAAAAAAAMf8/nsYUnwm35Gs/s1920/slide_1.jpg' title='Google'/></div>
<div class='gallery_text'><h2>Google</h2><p>Google is an American multinational corporation specializing in Internet-related services and products.</p><a href='http://www.google.com'>Open Google</a></div>
</li>
<li>
<div class='gallery_img'><img alt='Bing' src='https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-eGrPYj9dz1c/UyV9QgDIh5I/AAAAAAAAMgM/mlcDdyufQJs/s1920/slide_2.jpg' title='Bing'/></div>
<div class='gallery_text'><h2>Bing</h2><p>Bing is a search engine that brings together the best of search and people in your social networks to help you spend less time searching and more time doing.</p><a href='http://www.bing.com'>Open Bing</a></div>
</li>
<li>
<div class='gallery_img'><img alt='Yahoo' src='https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-L_s8vxgupPY/UyV9RKToZeI/AAAAAAAAMgQ/TWs-wy7lbrk/s1920/slide_3.jpg' title='Yahoo'/></div>
<div class='gallery_text'><h2>Yahoo</h2><p>Yahoo! Inc. is an American multinational Internet corporation headquartered in Sunnyvale, California.</p><a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Open Yahoo</a></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class='clear'/>
This Is The DIV Or Text After The Slider.
```

You can also see the live [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyathnom/1/) with error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the problem. You're trying to dynamically adjust the CSS `display` property of the `<li>` elements, alternating between `block` and `none`. But I don't think that's the right approach. *All* of the list item elements should be displayed and have `display:block;` at all times. The desired positioning can be achieved by setting the first `<li>` to `position:static;` (meaning it will be embedded in the graphical flow of the page), and all remaining `<li>` elements should be set to `position:absolute;` (meaning they will positionally "collapse" up to their parent container, thus causing them to sit snugly on top of the first `<li>`). To ensure only one `<li>` is visible at all times, it's enough to weaken the opacity of the others down to zero.

Thus, I made the following changes to your code:

1. Changed the first `<li>` from `<li style='position:relative!important;'>` to `<li style="position:static;">`.
2. Changed the `display` property of the `#gallery li` rule to `block`.
3. Commented out the 3 JS lines where you're messing with the .style.display property of `<li>` nodes.
4. Moved the definition of the `setOpacity()` function out of the `so_xfade()` function so that it will be stored at `window.setOpacity` and thus it will be accessible from all scopes (necessary for change #5).
5. Added the line `for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) setOpacity(imgs[i]);` to `so_init()` just after the line `imgs[0].xOpacity = .99;` to ensure that the opacities of all `<li>` elements are properly initialized.

I haven't used jsfiddle before, so I'm not sure if I did this right, but I clicked the "Update" button in the top menu bar and that dropped me into http://jsfiddle.net/yyathnom/2/, so I think you can use that to see my changes. Let me know if it works the way you want.

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't realize each slide needed link functionality. For link functionality the current slide needs to be not just visible, but at the front of the stack. This can be accomplished with z-index.

A complication is that z-index does not apply to statically-positioned elements, but that can easily be overcome by changing the position:static property to position:relative for the first list item (which is actually what you had originally!). Relatively positioned elements are still in-flow, they can just be moved and have their z-index set.

Another complication is that z-index interacts strangely with opacity; the final "computed" opacity seems to take into account both the opacity CSS style and the z-index. So an image with 50% opacity on top of another image with 50% will result in a different appearance if you swap the z-indexes of the two images, even leaving both opacities at 50%. I originally tried to swap the z-indexes when the two images were at approximately equal (50%) opacities, but the visual jerk was undesirable, so I ended up just changing the z-index at the end, at opacity zero.

So, made the following additional changes:

6. Added two global conceptual constants, ZINDEX_UNDERNEATH (1) and ZINDEX_CURRENTSLIDE (100). Larger z-indexes mean "more in front" and smaller mean "further back" within the stacking context.
7. Added initialization `imgs[i].style.zIndex = ZINDEX_UNDERNEATH;` for all but the first `<li>`, and `imgs[0].style.zIndex = ZINDEX_CURRENTSLIDE;` for the first `<li>`.
8. Added the following two lines to set the new current slide to the visible z-index, just before `current` is reassigned:

   ```
   imgs[current].style.zIndex = ZINDEX_UNDERNEATH;
   imgs[nIndex].style.zIndex = ZINDEX_CURRENTSLIDE;
   ```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/yyathnom/3/

**Edit:** To provide more detail on the original issue, it was caused by the fact that 2 of the 3 `<li>` elements had `position:absolute`, which means they were not in-flow, and although the first `<li>` had `position:relative`, meaning it *was* in-flow (but relatively movable), the code was regularly disabling it with `display:none`. Any element that is not in-flow will effectively have no "mass", meaning it won't push the following elements below it, but will instead let them "collapse up" to where it *would have* been positioned if it had been in-flow. Thus, when the first `<li>` was being set to `display:none` (which was when the other 2 `<li>`s were being displayed), there was no in-flow element there to keep the text following the slideshow images beneath the images, and so it collapsed up to the flow position of the images.

Comment: You tried to edit but you did something wrong. Now check your FIDDLE(http://jsfiddle.net/yyathnom/2/) and open every link of slider in new tab and see what page you are getting again and again.

Comment: Sorry, I see the problem; I didn't realize each `<li>` requires link functionality. Trying to find a solution using z-index, will get back to you soon.

Comment: Sorry, I did edit my answer about 17 hours ago, I just didn't add another comment. Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/yyathnom/3/ and let me know if it works the way you want.